# How to set 2 integer values to be the same

Tags: java, android, eclipse, integer, arrays

I am using a random variable, 2 string arrays and I am trying to set the 2 string arrays to have the same position value, I have tried all possible means, but none of them works. I am new to programming and don't fully understand java, just tid bits. I am just wondering if it is possible to set the integer values of different arrays to be the same.

My code is:

```
    Random r1 = new Random(), r2 = new Random();
    TextView txtDid, txtPhrase, txtFood, txtJokeQ, txtJokeA;
    ImageView imageDonate;
    int x, p, f, jq, ja;
    Button btnJokeNext;

    String[] JokeQArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
            "X", "Y", "Z" };

    String[] JokeAArray = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W",
            "X", "Y", "Z" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_tab);

        txtJokeQ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtJokeTextQ);
        txtJokeA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtJokeTextA);

        jq = r1.nextInt(JokeQArray.length);
        r2.nextInt(JokeAArray.length);
        txtJokeQ.setText(JokeQArray[jq].toString());
        txtJokeA.setText(JokeAArray[jq].toString());

        btnJokeNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnJokeNext);
        btnJokeNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                jq = r1.nextInt(JokeQArray.length);
                r2.nextInt(JokeAArray.length);
                txtJokeQ.setText(JokeQArray[jq].toString());
                txtJokeA.setText(JokeAArray[jq].toString());
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateJokeTextView();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    private void updateJokeTextView() {
        jq = r1.nextInt(JokeQArray.length);
        txtJokeQ.setText(JokeQArray[jq].toString());
        ja = r1.nextInt(JokeAArray.length);
        txtJokeA.setText(JokeAArray[ja].toString());
    }
}
```

I Practically messed up the code when I was trying to experiment different ways to do what I want to do. Hopefully, the code would make sense to you, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "different" arrays are a little too similar.

Comment: What do you mean by "*integer values of arrays*"? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I know following is not an answer to your question by my feedback and observation is too long to be described in comment section. So SORRY for this.

Couldn't get what exactly you problem is.
But after going through your code I have following beservation:

1. First two call to r2.nextInt(JokeAArray.length); in onCreate() and onClick() respectively are of no use because you are not using the generated random numbers.
2. Where as in updateJokeTextView() you are calling jq = r1.nextInt() as well as ja = r1.nextInt() both will generate two different random numbers which is again of no use because your question and answer will never match.
3. In updateJokeTextView(), instead of txtJokeA.setText(JokeAArray[ja].toString()); use txtJokeA.setText(JokeAArray[jq].toString());

Hope this solves you problem. If it doesn't, then please mention what exactly you want from your code.

Comment: Remember I already set a value for jq in the code above it, It would show me the strings for the Questions, not the answer

Answer (score 0):

As both the arrays have same values at same position; you can use
txtJokeQ.setText(JokeQArray[jq].toString());
txtJokeA.setText(JokeQArray[jq].toString());

Comment: that would not work because I would only be showing the array of questions in the 2 textviews, but I need to see a different text in the Answer Textview